# node process.argv is stripping caret (^)

Tags: node.js

I am trying to pass the caret character as an argument into node but `process.argv` is stripping off the caret. Passing `--bar=\^caret` did not work. Any solutions to prevent `process.argv` from stripping the caret?

```
//command:
npm run foo -- --bar=^caret

//foo.js:
console.log(process.argv);

//actual output:
[ 
  'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
  'C:\\cygwin64\\home\\me\\test\\scripts\\foo.js',
  '--bar=caret'
]

//expected output:
[ 
  'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
  'C:\\cygwin64\\home\\me\\test\\scripts\\foo.js',
  '--bar=^caret'
]
```

Comment: Is not Node.js the one that is stripping the caret. Probably the shell does. Try `"--bar=^caret"`

Comment: Ah, you're right. It is the shell that is stripping. I was previously running in PowerShell. Now I'm running in Windows Command Processor and wrapping my argument in double quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^` is Windows Command Processor (`cmd`)'s escape character. If you want to run a program form `cmd` with a literal `^` in an argument, you need to write `^^` instead or, in your case, wrap `--bar=^caret` with quotes.

These should work:

```
npm run foo -- "--bar=^caret"
npm run foo -- --bar=^^caret
```

From `HELP CMD`:

> ```
> The special characters that require quotes are:
>      <space>
>      &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~
> ```

This is not necessary in PowerShell or Bash, as their escape characters are, respectively, `` ` `` and `\`.